Nginx Configuration Error Duplicate location / Blocks
Please help me to resolve this issue.
ERROR:
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/new.coinbcx.com.conf:95
nginx: configuration file /www/server/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name new.coinbcx.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
    root /www/wwwroot/new.coinbcx.com/public;
    client_max_body_size 80M;

    #CERT-APPLY-CHECK--START
    # Configuration related to file verification for SSL certificate application - Do not delete
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/nginx/well-known/new.coinbcx.com.conf;
    #CERT-APPLY-CHECK--END
    #SSL-START SSL related configuration, do NOT delete or modify the next line of commented-out 404 rules
    #error_page 404/404.html;
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_START
    if ($server_port !~ 443){
        rewrite ^(/.*)$ https://$host$1 permanent;
    }
    #HTTP_TO_HTTPS_END
    ssl_certificate    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/new.coinbcx.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/new.coinbcx.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;
    #SSL-END
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    #ERROR-PAGE-START  Error page configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 502 /502.html;
    #ERROR-PAGE-END

    #PHP-INFO-START  PHP reference configuration, allowed to be commented, deleted or modified
    include enable-php-82.conf;
    #PHP-INFO-END

    #REWRITE-START URL rewrite rule reference, any modification will invalidate the rewrite rules set by the panel
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/new.coinbcx.com.conf;
    #REWRITE-END

    # Forbidden files or directories
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.env|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md)
    {
        return 404;
    }

    # Directory verification related settings for one-click application for SSL certificate
    location ~ \.well-known{
        allow all;
    }

    #Prohibit putting sensitive files in certificate verification directory
    if ( $uri ~ "^/\.well-known/.*\.(php|jsp|py|js|css|lua|ts|go|zip|tar\.gz|rar|7z|sql|bak)$" ) {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
        expires      30d;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log /dev/null;
    }

    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
        expires      12h;
        error_log /dev/null;
        access_log /dev/null; 
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-cgi-82.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass             https://127.0.0.1:6001;
        proxy_read_timeout     60;
        proxy_connect_timeout  60;
        proxy_redirect         off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
    access_log off; # Disable with aapanel
    error_log  /www/wwwlogs/new.coinbcx.com.error.log;
}

i want to keep both but don't know how to fix.
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

and
location / {
        proxy_pass             https://127.0.0.1:6001;
        proxy_read_timeout     60;
        proxy_connect_timeout  60;
        proxy_redirect         off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

Thanks.

That doesn't make sense. You can't have two conflicting configurations on the same virtual host.

You're absolutely right, having two conflicting location / blocks within the same server block is not valid. How should I merge them? Any suggestions?

you can't merge them. You need to either configure separate locations or separate servers (different name and/or port)

Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. Basically, I am working with WebSocket, and I was previously using this configuration:
location /socket.io {
proxy_pass https://localhost:6002;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

However, now I am working with Soketi, which is why I removed the /socket.io location block.
After removing it, I started facing the location / block conflict error.

Whatever the Soketi is, as well as Socket.IO, it is your web app responsibility to use it over some dedicated URL path.
